# HTML/CSS How do I align container to the center of page? CSS:

Tags: html, css

Trying to align my container to the center of page and the items inside to the center of the container. The alignment moves further to left when its zoomed out too. Looks uneven atm. Here's my HTML and CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/zr54b812/

```
CSS: 

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px outset brown;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;

}


HTML:

<!-- Cake Flavor-->
    <div class="grid-container">

    <div class ="grid-item">
    <h3>Cake Flavor</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">White</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">Chocolate</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">Yellow</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">Marble</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">Confetti (NEW)</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">Red Velvet (NEW)</label>
    </div>
    <!--Filling option-->
    <div class="grid-item">
        <h3>Filling Option</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">Lemon</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">Raspberry</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">Strawberry</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="style1">
        <label class="font1" for="style1">Bavarian Cream</label><br>
    
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: add `margin: 0 auto;` to the container's style

Comment: Oh man that worked thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align at center, use can use `margin: 0 auto;`. Besides that, you are creating one extra column in container, so set `grid-template-columns` to `auto auto` and not `auto auto auto`.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px outset brown;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` to class grid-container